# How to encode post data when using requests?

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding, python-requests, urlencode, parse-server

I'm writing a python script that sends push notifications to iOS devices via Parse Server. Some of these push notifications will contain location names with special characters such as æ, ø and å. On the iOS device, these characters show up as a � symbol.

Her is the relevant part of my python code:

```
import requests 

pushUrl = 'https://***/parse/push'
headers = {'X-Parse-Application-Id': '***',
           'X-Parse-Master-Key': '***',
           'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': '***',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
payload = '{"where": {"objectId": "' + installationId + '"}, "data": {"alert": "abc, æøå"}}'
response = requests.post(pushUrl, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

I have tried with different charsets, etc., but always get the same result. If I use CURL instead, the characters appear correctly on the device, so I know the problem is not with my Parse Server.

What to do?

Comment: Figured it out. The data argument is supposed to be a dictionary. Tried to do `json=payload` instead, but that didn't work. `data=json.dumps(payload)` however did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Requests(v2.21.0)'s documents is wrote:

> Your dictionary of data will automatically be form-encoded when the request is made.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests